# Cut out partially repeated lines

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm grepping a log file with the following command:

```
grep "System has completed" my_log.log
```

and getting something like

```
2019-12-07 17:03:09.527   System has completed 0 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:20.936   System has completed 4 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:32.381   System has completed 5 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:44.053   System has completed 5 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:55.753   System has completed 21 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:07.252   System has completed 22 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:18.728   System has completed 28 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:30.181   System has completed 28 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:41.627   System has completed 28 of 15778 files
```

I want to further process these results to cut out the lines with repeated numbers of completed files so that the output is

```
2019-12-07 17:03:09.527   System has completed 0 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:20.936   System has completed 4 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:32.381   System has completed 5 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:03:55.753   System has completed 21 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:07.252   System has completed 22 of 15778 files
2019-12-07 17:04:18.728   System has completed 28 of 15778 files
```

Keeping only the first line when multiple lines repeat the same number. Simply filtering all unique lines is not possible because of the timestamps. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number will always be in the same position you can use `sort`:

```
grep "System has completed" my_log.log | sort -unk6,6
```

Or `uniq`:

```
grep "System has completed" my_log.log | uniq -f2
```